# Mod tests not working in Rust smart contract for near blockchain

Tags: rust

```
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;
    use near_sdk::MockedBlockchain;
    use near_sdk::{testing_env, VMContext};
    fn get_context(predecessor_account_id: String, storage_usage: u64) -> VMContext {
        VMContext {
            current_account_id: "alice.testnet".to_string(),
            signer_account_id: "jane.testnet".to_string(),
            signer_account_pk: vec![0, 1, 2],
            predecessor_account_id,
            input: vec![],
            block_index: 0,
            block_timestamp: 0,
            account_balance: 0,
            account_locked_balance: 0,
            storage_usage,
            attached_deposit: 0,
            prepaid_gas: 10u64.pow(18),
            random_seed: vec![0, 1, 2],
            is_view: false,
            output_data_receivers: vec![],
            epoch_height: 19,
        }
    }
}
```

Error:
[image]

CODE FROM: https://docs.near.org/docs/develop/contracts/rust/intro

To write tests for smart contracts in rust I referred to this website article, link is pasted above. Now I copied the boilerplate code for cargo.toml and the test config(code to that is the above - 1st from the top). I get this error which I cannot debug, I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: It looks like you're missing a `}` from whatever is above and you have one too many `}` below.

Comment: The extra bracket has been removed but the problem is with the statement ``mod tests``

Comment: *You're missing a `}` from whatever is above*, so the `mod test` is nested in whatever trait or impl block you have, which is not allowed.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to contain a code sample _that by itself causes the error_ (you can test with the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/)). For syntax issues, it doesn't need to be a complete program, but it does need to actually contain the problem — the code currently in your question has valid syntax.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

To clarify what others have pointed out in the comments, it looks like you have something like this:

```rust
struct Foo {
  // whatever
}

impl Foo {
  fn some_function() {
    // whatever
  }

// this closing brace is missing
// }

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {

}
```

You cannot define a module inside an `impl` block, so this out of order brace is causing the "module is not supported in `trait`s or `impl`s" error you see.